# How to customize dhtmlxscheduler.js file for adding some fields in popup?

Tags: dhtmlx

I have some requirement for dhtmlx scheduler, here I would like edit the event and add one text box and one button.Can you please suggest me how we can cusomize the .js(compressed) file.
Is there any separate .js files are availble for  Development version.
If any please suggest me.[image]

Thanks,
Rajasekhar

Comment: What does the button do? Is it a submit button or a do something to the textbox button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution:
Modify the file `dhtmlxscheduler.js`  i mean  `section` fields :

```
lightbox: {
        sections: [
            { name: "description", height: 40, map_to: "text", type: "textarea", focus: true },
            { name: "Note", height: 40, map_to: "text", type: "textarea", focus: true },
            { name: "Status", height: 40, map_to: "text", type: "textarea", focus: true },
            { name: "Type", height: 40, map_to: "text", type: "textarea", focus: true },
            { name: "Sequence", height: 40, map_to: "text", type: "textarea", focus: true },
            {name: "time", height: 72, type: "time", map_to: "auto"}
        ]
    },
```

and

```
labels:{
        dhx_cal_today_button:"Today",
        day_tab:"Day",
        week_tab:"Week",
        month_tab:"Month",
        new_event:"Nouvelle Tache",
        icon_save:"Save",
        icon_cancel:"Cancel",
        icon_details:"Details",
        icon_edit:"Edit",
        icon_delete:"Delete",
        confirm_closing:"",//Your changes will be lost, are your sure ?
        confirm_deleting:"Event will be deleted permanently, are you sure?",
        section_description: "Description",
        section_Note: "Note",
        section_Status: "Status",
        section_Type: "Type",
        section_Sequence: "Sequence",
        section_time:"Periode",
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to configure the details of this form (or lightbox).

The documentation on how to do this is [here](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxscheduler%3acustom_details_form)

There is no need to edit the main dhtmlx source for this.