# Dhtmlx scheduler in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

I am using [`DHTMLX Scheduler`](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/) in my MVC4 application. I need to set the reminder in scheduler.

If the user set the reminder for a particular appointment for example before 2 days, automatically email alert should be sent to the user.

**Is it possible to include the reminder in scheduler Or Whether any other option is there to add reminder?**

And My code for scheduler is

```
public ActionResult CalendarView(int id, tblUser user, int? Userid)
        {
 var scheduler = new DHXScheduler(this);

                scheduler.Skin = DHXScheduler.Skins.Flat;
                scheduler.Data.Loader.PreventCache();
                scheduler.EnableDynamicLoading(SchedulerDataLoader.DynamicalLoadingMode.Week);
                scheduler.Extensions.Add(SchedulerExtensions.Extension.Recurring);
                //scheduler.Extensions.Add(SchedulerExtensions.Extension.ActiveLinks);

                //scheduler.Extensions.Add(SchedulerExtensions.Extension.Collision);

                scheduler.Extensions.Add(SchedulerExtensions.Extension.Limit);
  scheduler.LoadData = true;
                scheduler.EnableDataprocessor = true;
                scheduler.Config.show_loading = true;
  int idays = System.DateTime.Now.Day - 1;
                int imonths = System.DateTime.Now.Month;
                int iyears = System.DateTime.Now.Year;
                int hours = System.DateTime.Now.Hour;
                int minute = System.DateTime.Now.Minute;
                int second = System.DateTime.Now.Second;

                scheduler.TimeSpans.Add(new DHXBlockTime()
                {
                    StartDate = new DateTime(2014, 2, 10),
                    EndDate = new DateTime(iyears, imonths, idays + 1, hours, minute, second),

                });
                Session["BUId"] = id;
                var parameter = new SqlParameter[1];
                parameter[0] = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "UserId", Value = id };
                List<Appt> cm = new List<Appt>();
                using (SYTEntities context = new SYTEntities())
                {
                    cm = context.Database.SqlQuery<Appt>("exec spHoliday @UserId", parameter).ToList();

                }

                foreach (var cp in cm)
                {
                    iyear = cp.HolidayDate.Year;
                    imonth = cp.HolidayDate.Month;
                    iday = cp.HolidayDate.Day;

                    scheduler.TimeSpans.Add(new DHXMarkTime()
                    {

                        StartDate = new DateTime(iyear, imonth, iday),       //new DateTime(2015, 8, 06), //hl.HolidayDate ?? default(DateTime),    
                        EndDate = new DateTime(iyear, imonth, iday + 1),
                        //  Day = DayOfWeek.Friday,

                        CssClass = "red_section",
                        HTML = "hos",
                        SpanType = DHXTimeSpan.Type.BlockEvents
                    });
                }
    scheduler.BeforeInit.Add("schedulerClient.init()");


                return View(scheduler);
            }
```

[image]

Comment: I think you should be custom options add in new event popup. Might be it will be [help full](http://blog.scheduler-net.com/post/minor-update-switch-on-the-fly-lightboxes.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't get correctly. Will you tell me how to add custom options in event popup because it is inbuilt pop up.

Comment: Refer [Custom Lightbox dhtmlx](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/custom_details_form.html) and [How to customize dhtmlxscheduler.js file for adding some fields in popup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13271498/how-to-customize-dhtmlxscheduler-js-file-for-adding-some-fields-in-popup)

Comment: [Custom Lightbox Control](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/custom_lightbox_editor.html)

Comment: Thanks. It is useful for me